# How do I replace multiple character strings in a column to numbers

Tags: r, replace, gsub

I am sure this is a simple question, but have found nothing online to clarify. I am working on a CSV file in R and have a column labeled Gender with 2 levels "M" and "F". I am trying to change the variables so that F=1 and M=0, both with a numeric type. What code do I need to plug in to change gender?

I have tried using gsub, the replace function, and code with this format:

```
Test[Test$Gender == "F",]$Gender = 1
```

When I type in the code above it returns the error message:

> Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Test$Gender == "F", , value = list(
>   :    missing values are not allowed in subscripted assignments of data
>   frames

What do I need to do in order to properly replace M and F with 0 and 1?

Comment: `Test %>% mutate(Gender = ifelse(Gender == "M",1,0))`

Answer (score 3):

One possible way to do it, through manipulation of the levels of `Gender`:

```
#dummy data:
Test = data.frame(Gender = factor(sample(c('M','F'), replace=T, size=10)))
# solution:    
Test$Gender = as.integer(factor(Test$Gender, levels=c('F','M')))-1
```

You can use `levels` to choose which level (M or F) gets the first value.

Comment: Got it, thanks so much! I had to use Gender = gsub(2, 0, Gender) and then Gender = as.numeric(Gender), but it now looks as it should have. Thank you for your help!

Comment: `gsub` is meant for character vectors, and here you have a simpler case, where you're dealing with a factor. So just manipulating the levels is a good approach.

Answer (score 2):

Using `Tidyverse` approach:

```
library(tidyverse)
Test <- data.frame(Gender=c("F","M","F","M"))
Test %>% 
    mutate(Gender_mod=case_when(
        Gender=="F" ~ 1,
        Gender=="M" ~ 0
    )
```

and you create a new variable encoding the old one in a new one with desiderd values.

```
  Gender Gender_mod
1      F          1
2      M          0
3      F          1
4      M          0
```

Or you may decide to replace the values in the original variable:

```
Test %>% 
   mutate(Gender=as.numeric(str_replace_all(string=Gender,pattern=c("F","M"),replacement=c("1","0"))))
```

and this is the output:

```
  Gender
1      1
2      0
3      1
4      0
```